# How can i submit data to a php page without going to that page right away?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to take form data from user input- i.e. radio buttons and use that to apply search filters to a database search.

However there are specific parameters which are giving me difficulty.

Specifically: The search filter options pane is a static fixture on the main page of the site. The query to be modified by the search filters is a separate php page which is called by an ajax function to display search results in the middle of the page without page refresh.

Is it even possible to submit variable values to another php page without going to that page and processing the php immediately? Or will the variables not be stored like that?

The code is too long but I'll give basic pseudocode:

- Form action="Query Page to receive user input.php"
- Some radio buttons:

  - 20
  - 15
  - 10

- Submit button--> Submits the radio button value to QueryPage.php but does not redirect
- User clicks a category link (i.e. fitness) that calls the ajax function which displays the output of QueryPage.php. At this point QueryPage.php should perform the search with the specific user input filters that were selected earlier.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand correctly:

You're basically saying that your radio buttons will modify the search results, based on the what user selected?

If that's the case, I can think of 2 options:

1- When you make the ajax request for the search, first, grab the user input and send it to the QueryPage.php file with the search query. Do you have access to that function?
2- Post the user input using ajax (are you using jQuery or some other library for this?) to a UserInput.php file, where you'll store that data on the session, and then from QueryPage.php you just access the session and grab the values sent previously.

Does that answer your question? Sorry if it doens't, it's a bit hard to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQUERY and its events method. For example change,click,hover. In your case you want to use radio buttons, so you might wanna use the click event for that.

```
$("#radio").click(function () {
// SEND HTTP REQUEST
});
```

http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-select-a-radio-button-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could just use [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), or [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`cURL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php). This will post your data to the specified page without redirecting.

Example using .post()

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm", fieldname: "your value" } );
```